# How to add a layer to a maptheme in QGIS with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, maptheme

I am wrestling to add a layer in a maptheme (as in collection of visible layers, part of QGSmapThemeCollection) with PyQGIS.
I am able to read the different themes (which are only namestrings) and to show the layerIDs in a theme with mapThemeVisibleLayerIds(myTheme).

```
troot = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
tmodel = iface.layerTreeView().layerTreeModel()
mtc = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
mapThemes = mtc.mapThemes()

for mt in mapThemes:
    print(mt)
    mtc.applyTheme(mt,troot,tmodel)
    for lid in mtc.mapThemeVisibleLayerIds(mt):
        print('     ' + lid)
```

But I see no way to add a layer(ID) to a theme.
I was hoping on something like:

```
mt.addLayer('my_layer')
mt.removeLayer('old_layer')
```

It seems clear it has to do with MapThemeRecord and MapthemeLayerRecord, but I have no idea how to approach it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were correct to assume it has something to with `MapThemeRecord` and `MapThemeLayerRecord` classes. The workflow of adding a layer to an existing maptheme will be as follows:

1. Get the `MapThemeRecord` object from the collection
2. Create a new `MapThemeLayerRecord` from the layer you want to add
3. Add the `MapThemeLayerRecord` to the `MapThemeRecord` from step 1
4. Update the collection of mapthemes with the changed `MapThemeRecord`

And in code this process will look like the following example. Of course you need to adapt the theme name and layer reference to your needs.

```py
mtc = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()

theme_name = 'My Theme'
layer_to_add = iface.activeLayer()

theme_state = mtc.mapThemeState(theme_name)
layer_record = QgsMapThemeCollection.MapThemeLayerRecord(layer_to_add)
theme_state.addLayerRecord(layer_record)
mtc.update(theme_name, theme_state)
```

Comment: Thanks works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

With the help of CodeBard I came up with this to replace a layer in all themes:

```
def lay_replace_in_theme(lay_replace, lay_with):        
    mtc = QgsProject.instance().mapThemeCollection()
    mts = mtc.mapThemes()

    for mt in mts:
        for lid in mtc.mapThemeVisibleLayerIds(mt):
            if lid == lay_replace.id():
                theme_state = mtc.mapThemeState(mt)
                lrec_repl = mtc.MapThemeLayerRecord(lay_replace)
                lrec_with = mtc.MapThemeLayerRecord(lay_with)
                theme_state.removeLayerRecord(lay_replace)      #strangely enough this must be a layer
                mtc.update(mt, theme_state)     
                theme_state.addLayerRecord(lrec_with)       #and this must be a layerrecord as expected
                mtc.update(mt, theme_state)
```

The first update-action is not really necessary, and it turns out that the the first mapThemeLayerRecord is also not necessarry(?).